# installed version of Rubygems is outdated, but I actually have a newer version installed?

Tags: ruby, hosting

I suspect this is a problem with my hosting setup, not Rubygems. Hopefully someone can help me get it sorted out.

I recently moved my Drupal site from my OS X development server to a Greengeeks hosting site. I am now attempting to run Drush omega-guard on that server. When I attempt to do it, I get an error that says my installed version of Rubygems (1.3.7) is outdated and I need 1.8 or above. However, when I do a "ruby -v" it tells me I have 1.8.7 installed.

Trying to do a bundle install has also caused a host of problems with it not being able to find bundle even after I have just installed it successfully.

Does anyone have any advice. I very much appreciate the help. I would have added a screenshot, but I do not yet have the reputation.

Comment: Try asking this on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

Emailing Greengeeks, I found out that they do not support Ruby Gems on shared hosting.

I am still a little unclear as to whether this means I cannot set it up or whether they are not going to assist me with it in any way. But either way it is a pain in the ass.